# Deploy Go Service in production with Docker

Tags: git, docker, go

I'm working on a Go service with Docker, and thinking that as it is compiled, to deploy code in production, I just need the docker compose, and the Docker image published on my registry.

As I come from PHP world, I am used to clone my whole project to deploy it.

Is there any way I could deploy my project only with docker-compose file ?

I saw on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912545/how-to-retrive-a-single-file-from-github-using-git) that I can git clone only a single file, but it feels that it is not a good way to do, what is the best practice to deploy a Go Microservice with Docker ?

Comment: In fact, you should be able to deploy your project with an image pushed to a Docker registry and a `docker-compose.yml` file mentioning that registry.  That's true for both Go and PHP.  What specific problem are you encountering?

Comment: @David Maze I have no problem, but I m looking g for a good workflow to deploy to prod with docker and go. I understand that my whole source code is not needed, but how should I get my docker-compose files if I dont get it from git?

Comment: Of course you can deploy Go programs in Docker. This has been done thousands or millions of times. What have you tried? Show your relevant code/configuration/Dockerfile. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @filmzy, not asking if it is possible ! It is not about code, it is about workflow.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate problems in your question, and I am not sure which ones you're looking for an answer for.

Q1: What's a good way to create a Dockerfile for my Go project
A1: Have a look at the example here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/. If you need to git clone, clone the entire source tree, as you would with php...

Q2: Now that I have my image, how do I use it in production.
A2: Make sure it's available on a repository (public or private) somewhere. Then reference that image (using it's full name, which includes the FQDN of the repo server, if you aren't using Docker Hub) when starting your container. There's no need to "git clone" anything at this point...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frank. I have no issue with q1. I already have a docker image on AWS ECR. Now I understand the source code is not needed, so it is probably a bad practice to put it on servers, but should I write locally my docker compose ?

Comment: It depends how you want to deploy to production. Is it a stand-alone docker host? Then a docker-compose.yaml file would be the best solution, as that file will describe your application (image, volumes it might need, exposed ports, etc), and that file could/should be stored in git, so it's under version control. If you would deploy to a Swarm cluster, you can use that same file to create a "stack". If you are deploying to a Kube cluster, a kube deployment.yaml file would be a better option. But the main thing is that your app is in the image. So you don't need source files on the server.

Comment: for now I stick with docker compose as I have several container in my app. Question is, should I git my deploy files in the same repo as my source code ? Is it a bad practice to have it all in one repo ?

Comment: There's no right and bad answer to that question. I would keep the compose-file in the same repo, as it is tied to that piece of software ... But then I know companies that keep them in a separate repo because of permissions.

Comment: Ok, I work in a startup, so my team is not big enough to have this kind of issue. But isn't it better for security expose less source code as possible ? If I let the docker compose files in the same git, I will link the server to my source code. This is my concern.

Comment: In that case: use a different repo.